# In which scenario '=' used and '=>' used in scala?

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and I confused little bit with = and =>, I don't know in which scenario exactly **=** used and **=>** used.

Comment: = is for assignemnet and => to define the anonymous function

Comment: Without a grasp of the basics, don't worry about `=>`. It's a relatively advanced thing you shouldn't need to use unless you're intentionally trying to define anonymous functions, as @Raman says (or using things like `.map()`).

Answer (score 1):

@RamanMishra's comment is correct, however I would like to expand it a bit hopping it becomes more clear to you.

`a = b` means `a` is now **equals** to `b` *(in the imperative meaning of the word, which is better understood as **assignment**)*.
It is used in many places, including when defining a  [**function\method**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala), for example

```
def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
```

The above statement can be readed as:
*"We defined a **function** with name `sum` which takes two parameters (a & b) both of type `Int` and returns an `Int`. And its **body\implementation** is 'equals' to `a + b`"*.

`a => b` means, there is a **function** which takes a parameters list `a` and has a body `b`, it is used a couple of places, including anonymous functions and higher-order functions.

```
val anonymous: Int => Int = x => x + 1
```

The above statement can be readed as:
*"We defined a value called `anonymous`, whose type is a **function** with one parameter of type `Int` and a return type `Int`, which is 'equals' to the 'anonymous' function which takes one parameter `x` (its type is inferred in by the context, in this type the explicit type signature before) and its **body** is `x + 1`"*

```
def higherOrder(x: Int, f: Int => Int): Int = f(x)
```

The above statement can be readed as:
*"There is a **function** (`sum`), which takes another **function** as a parameter (`f`), the later is a function of type `Int` to `Int`"*.

---

#### Edit

As @Aki suggested, the `=>` is also used in pattern matching to separate the cases and the block of code to execute for each one.

```
def fact(n: Long): Long = n match {
  case 0L => 1L
  case n  => n * fact(n - 1)
}
```

*"This is somewhat similar to a **parameter list** `=>` **function body**, as the above examples"*.

---

***PS:** This is a 101 Scala question, SO is not the best place for such questions, because there is probably enough resources on the internet - like [this cheatsheet](https://docs.scala-lang.org/cheatsheets/index.html), or better places to ask - like the [scala gitter channel](https://gitter.im/scala/scala)*.

Comment: You could also mention that the arrow is used in pattern matching after cases.

Comment: @Aki Good catch! - I totally forgot about it, I will edit the answer in a moment, thanks!